# trigger two according to data

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables and I have one trigger from table D_ISI in table 2 to trigger MAX_ISI value to write to the other table. Can you help me solve the trigger problem?

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `ISI_YUKSEK_ISE` BEFORE INSERT ON `TB1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE
        D_ISI INT ;
    SET
        D_ISI = NEW.D_ISI ; IF 
        (SELECT D_ISI = NEW.D_ISI FROM TB1,TB2 WHERE TB2.CIHAZ_ID=TB1.CIHAZ_KODU AND TB1.D_ISI >= TB2.MAX_ISI OR TB1.D_ISI <= TB2.MIN_ISI) THEN
    INSERT
INTO
    TB3(CIHAZ_KODU,D_ISI)
VALUES(NEW.CIHAZ_KODU,NEW.D_ISI) ;
END IF ; END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: formattingyourcodewillmakeiteasierforpeopletoreadandprobablygetyourquestionabetterreception

Comment: Can I help you edit the CODE?

Comment: This question needs work. 'one trigger from table D_ISI in table 2 ' - did you mean column d in what table? Please try to keep the text in the question and published code consistant. AND what problem - did you have a syntax error or did the trigger not fire or did the trigger fire but no give you the result you expected? Sample data and expected result would help as would a statement of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. According to MAX_ISI in the DEVICES table, I would like D_ISI> or <to trigger. in the example above does not do this